# jquery animate background image between two classes

Tags: jquery, html, css, user-interface

I've been away from programming for a while and can't quite get my head around this.

I have one div, with two classes. On hover, I want to switch the bg image, easily done with CSS.

But I'd like it to have a fade effect. I though this would be as easy as using `toggleClass` with jQuery UI but it doesn't give the desired effect.

```
$(".clicker").hover( function() {
    $(this).parent().toggleClass("anim", 500);
});​
```

How can I get the fade effect between the two classes?

[Live example here](http://jsfiddle.net/Kyle_Sevenoaks/VfqLA/).

Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### *[jsBin demo](http://jsbin.com/udezuh/edit#javascript,html,live)*

Use two DIVs, and toggle the visibility of the inner one (`#lighter_2`)

```
<div id="lighter">     
    <div id="lighter_2"></div>     
    <p class="clicker">Darkspore</p>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#lighter{
    position:relative;
    background: url(http://placehold.it/250x250/f0f);
    width: 100%;
    height: 400px;
}

#lighter_2{
    display:none;
    position:absolute;
    background: url(http://placehold.it/250x250/cf5);
    width: 100%;
    height: 400px;
}

.clicker{
    position:relative;
    z-index:2;
    background: #fff;
    cursor:pointer;
}
```

And just toggle that div on `hover`

```
$('.clicker').hover(function(){
  $('#lighter_2').stop().fadeTo(800,1);
},function(){
  $('#lighter_2').stop().fadeTo(800,0);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

But is it possible for jQuery UI to make animation of toggling `background-image`?

I'd prefer using simple fading effect:

```
$(".clicker").hover(function() {
    $(this).parent().fadeOut(500, function() {
        $(this).toggleClass("anim").fadeIn(500);
    });
});​
```

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/VfqLA/2/

Answer (score 0):

You would use .fadeIn() and .fadeOut() see: http://api.jquery.com/fadeOut/

**Note**
You could fadeOut() the old and in the next call fadeIn() the new, which should transition the two if thats what you are going for.